# For $e(g, d) = c $, can we compute $d$, given others

Tags: pairings

Given $$e(g, d)  = c $$
where,

- $e$ is bilinear pairing function chosen by the user/attacker,
- the values of $g$ and $c$ are known
- $g, d ∈ \mathbb{G}_1$ , $c$ depends upon the $e$

can we somehow compute the value of $d$

In a high level, I am asking if there exists a function $f$ that, in one way is the inverse of a $e$ can be used to compute $d$?

Comment: What you describe is the so called pairing inversion problem. You may look [here](http://ellipticnews.wordpress.com/2013/11/06/recent-work-on-pairing-inversion/) for some pointers to literature.

Comment: Thanks, the blog was quite interesting, and I am still going through it (for the second time). In the mean while, could I naively ask, if there is a "fault", or "a cheat", to compute the inverse of a pairing "quickly"? Say, I am looking from an attackers point of view, so an existential "cheat" would do fine as well.